# Python Convert ordered list of relative changes to absolute changes

Tags: python

Let's assume I have a set of objects containing: (relative change, time of change):

```
(+1,0) (-1, 1) (+1,3) (+1, 3) (-1, 5) (+1, 9)
```

Now I want to replace the relative changes by their absolute value, starting at 0:

```
(1,0) (0, 1) (1,3) (2, 3) (1, 5) (2, 9)
 0+1   0+1-1  0+1-1+1 ...
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there a Python function that allows me to

- Iterate over a (ordered) list of objects
- Internally store an absolute value
- read the change from each object, update the internal absolute value
- replace the relative change with the absolute value

Comment: If the values are `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, what would your output be?

Comment: @robert - If I understand the question correctly, the output would be `[(a, b), (a+c, d)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [(+1,0), (-1, 1), (+1,3), (+1, 3), (-1, 5), (+1, 9)]
>>> [(sum(x[0] for x in data[:i+1]), data[i][1]) for i in range(len(data))]
[(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 5), (2, 9)]
```

Or slightly more efficiently (doesn't call `sum()` for each value):

```
result = [data[0]]
for change, t in data[1:]:
    result.append((result[-1][0]+change, t))
```

Since you said these are objects, you will probably need to replace the indexing with an attribute get, for example the `x[0]` in `sum(x[0] for x in data[:i+1])` might become `x.change`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with a list comprehension, but this seems more like a job for a generator to me, given the specific terms of your request. This is a very generalized solution that should work with both sequences and iterators. It performs the equivalent of Haskell's `scanl` function on the iterable passed to it, with an optional initial value as the last argument.

The first argument should be a function that takes two arguments -- the current accumulated state and the next item in the sequence -- and returns the next accumulated state. It could be as simple as `operator.add` or something more complex.

```
>>> def scan(f, seq, init=None):
...     seq = iter(seq)
...     state = seq.next() if init is None else init
...     yield state
...     for i in seq:
...         state = f(state, i)
...         yield state
```

Accumulated summation (i.e. triangular numbers):

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(scan(operator.add, range(10)))
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Starting with a different initial value:

```
>>> list(scan(operator.add, range(1, 10), 10))
[10, 11, 13, 16, 20, 25, 31, 38, 46, 55]
```

Applied to your problem:

```
>>> diffs = [(1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 3), (-1, 5), (1, 9)]
>>> list(scan(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], y[1]), diffs))
[(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 5), (2, 9)]
```

With a different initial value, just for the fun of it.

```
>>> list(scan(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], y[1]), diffs, (5, -1)))
[(5, -1), (6, 0), (5, 1), (6, 3), (7, 3), (6, 5), (7, 9)]
```